# Yield of a (sub)parse tree in Rascal

Tags: yield, rascal

How can I obtain the yield of (sub)parse tree in Rascal, i.e., the text that is associated to a subtree?
For ex., during a visit I encounter a Declaration (with Java/M3) and now I want to get the text of this declaration.
I have tried "unparse", but this gives "does not match any of the declared (overloaded) signature patterns :unparse(Tree)", I guess that it works only for a top sort/starting symbol.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest solutions is using a string template and inserting your subtree in it -- assuming that your subtree is `d`:

```
"<d>"
```

This will automatically unparse `d`. More sophisticated pretty printing is currently missing but is on our todo list.